# Java Operator Precedence issue for a simple equation

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I am trying to implement a simple equation in Java but keep getting the wrong answer apparently due to operator precedence which I am unable to understand.

The equation is:

**NewMean = ((N-1) / N) * OldMean + (Xn / N)**

in a simple example:
N = 6 ; OldMean = 6 ; Xn = 16

So,
NewMean = 5/6 * 6 + 16/6 = 7.6667 **(Correct answer)**

but in code implementation on Java i get wrong answer (2.6665):

```
double NewMean = ((N-1)/N)*oldMean + (Xn/N);
```

Comment: What are the type of Xn, oldMean and N ? Are they all double ?

Comment: Hi Thanks. Type Xn is double and N is int. and now after changing N to double I am getting the correct result.

Comment: Since `N` is an `int`, you get the issue addressed in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/5221149). Simplest fix is to change `1` to `1d`. Assuming `Xn` is a `double`, that will correct result to be `7.666666666666666`

Comment: Please stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names should start with lowercase. For instance, `N` should be `n` and `NewMean` should be `newMean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `N` variable is type `int`, then `((N-1) / N)` is computed using integer division and will round 5/6 down to 0. Change `N` to a floating-point type and you should get the correct answer.

Comment: To make it use double `(N-1.0)/N` or `1 - 1.0 / N`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Most minimal fix: Change `1` to `1d`.